# rescale and inverse_transform not returning predicted and actual values in original scale for LSTM multivariate time-series forecast

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I'm currently building an LSTM multivariate time-series model to predict one output at current time (t) using 22 features from the previous timestamp (t-1) as inputs. I've been following the instructions from [this example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/), and everything seems to be working correctly, but the one issue I'm having involves the final inverse_transform() functions.

Specifically, I'm expecting that once I invert the scaling for both the forecasted values and the actual values, the output will be in the same units as the original data before I normalized and transformed my dataset. The variable I'm trying to predict has a mean of around 29.186, but when I run inverse_transform() and plot the predictions against the actuals, the output of my results ranges from 3.30 - 3.55.

It could be that I've made a simple error slicing the array, or it could be something completely different, but I can't seem to identify the root cause of why my predicted and actual values aren't in the same units as the data before I transformed everything.

For additional context, here's the printed output of train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape:

```
(1804950, 1, 22) (1804950,) (849389, 1, 22) (849389,)
```

Here's the relevant parts of my code:

```
# ensure all data is float
values = ips_data.values.astype('float32')

# normalize features
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)

# frame as supervised learning
ips_reframed = series_to_supervised(scaled, 1, 1)

# drop a bunch of columns I don't want to predict
ips_reframed.drop(ips_reframed.columns[[22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,42,43]], axis=1, inplace=True)
# print(ips_reframed.head())

# split into train and test sets
values = ips_reframed.values
# n_train_hours = (365 * 24 * 60) * 3
n_train_hours = int(len(values) * 0.68)
train = values[:n_train_hours, :]
test = values[n_train_hours:, :]

# split into input and outputs
train_X, train_y = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
test_X, test_y = test[:, :-1], test[:, -1]

# reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], 1, test_X.shape[1]))
# print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)

# design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(50))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("linear"))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

# fit network
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=1000, 
validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)

# plot history
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# make a prediction
yhat = model.predict(test_X)

# invert scaling for forecast
test_X = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], test_X.shape[2]))
inv_yhat = concatenate((yhat, test_X[:, 1:]), axis=1)
inv_yhat = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_yhat)
inv_yhat = inv_yhat[:,0]

# invert scaling for actual
test_y = test_y.reshape((len(test_y), 1))
inv_y = concatenate((test_y, test_X[:, 1:]), axis=1)
inv_y = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_y)
inv_y = inv_y[:,0]

# calculate RMSE
rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(inv_y, inv_yhat))
# print('Test RMSE: %.3f' % rmse)

# plotting the predictions
plt.plot(inv_yhat[-100:], label='predictions')
plt.plot(inv_y[-100:], label='actual')
plt.title("Prediction vs. Actual")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Please let me know if you need any additional information or context, and thank you so much for your help!